# hive Expression Not In Group By Key (group by - having)

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, top-n

I need to execute this query to create a table of the average growth rate for each state and industry

```
create table industry_growth as select state,sub_industry, avg(growth_percent)ind_growth from company_growth group by state, sub_industry having count(sub_industry>2);
```

I am reading from this table

```
state                   string                                      
sub_industry            string                                      
companyname             string                                      
growth_percent          double
```

but i keep getting this error

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:45 Expression not in
> GROUP BY key 'sub_industry'

help!

Comment: If sub_industry is in group by then this can not work: having count(sub_industry>2). What are you are trying to acheve? Please explain the task

Comment: im trying to get the best-growing industry by each state

Comment: I think bracket is the problem. Could you pls try this  `create table industry_growth as select state,sub_industry, avg(growth_percent)ind_growth from company_growth group by state, sub_industry having count(sub_industry)>2;` - Pls note i put >2 outside the count. I am not sure about your logic though.

Comment: Please provide some representative data example and expected result

Comment: what count(sub_industry>2) should do? Do you need two best - growing pwr state or what exaxtly?

Answer (score 0):

If you need top-n sub-industies per state, calculate dense_rank and filter how many top industries per state do you want. This query will print top 2 sub-industries per state. If you need only 1 top sub-industry per state, change filter in the where clause to be `where rnk = 1`. If two industries have the same ind_growth, they will receive the same rank and you will get two rows instead of one. row_number() instead of dense_rank() will assign 1 to only one record.

```
create table industry_growth as 

select state, sub_industry, ind_growth
from
(
select state, sub_industry, ind_growth , 
       dense_rank() over(partition by state, order by ind_growth desc) rnk
from
  (
   select state, sub_industry, avg(growth_percent) ind_growth 
     from company_growth group by state, sub_industry
  ) s 
) s where rnk <= 2 --for two most performing sub-industries per state
                   --rnk=1 is the most performing sub-industry per state
```